# I think i found a SO copy

Tags: discussion

I was searching for an answer on SO about something and decided to find help on other website. I found http://qaoverflow.com/.
I then immediately realized the questions and answers were the EXACT same as on SO, and it seems a lot of other websites are being copied here too. Can someone take down this website?

Comment: You should report such clones (AKA Stack Content Republishers Attributing Poorly and/or Excelling at Ranking or SCRAPERs) from http://stackoverflow.com/contact.